# Does Ubuntu-tv work with the mythbackend or tvheadend?

Tags: tv, mythtv, ubuntu-tv

The mythbackend or tvheadend does it work for streaming live tv to smart tv (ubuntu-tv).

Answer (score 1):

I've creating a scope for Ubuntu-TV that should stream content from a MythTV backend, but it isn't ready yet. It should be usable from a regular Unity setup as well, providing you have the video lens installed.